# The Difference Between Calling and Returning a Recursive Function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

Can someone please explain with a simple example what precisely is the difference between calling and returning a recursive function in c++?

Here is my code which seeks to find a character in a string recursively.  It works fine when I just call find(); the function displays an integer value, But, when I code `return find(letter,word)`, it gives the correct result as either a 1 or 0. Thanks

```
 bool find(char f,string str)
    {
        static int len = str.length() - 1;
        static int count = 1;
        if (len<0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

        if (str[len] == f)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            len--;
            return find(f, str);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "returning a function" do you mean "returning **from** a function?"

Comment: Can you please explain the problem you are facing with an example

Comment: `return find(f, str);` doesn't "return a function". It calls a function, obtains its return value, and then returns the same value. If that's what you are asking.

Comment: I think that as you do more testing you'll find your function doesn't work fine. Because you use static variable it will work the **first** time you call it, it's won't work the **second** time you call it. The problem is that static variables only get initialised once, not each time you call the function from your main program (which is clearly what you are expecting). Rewrite the function without static variables, then it will work.

Comment: i used static variable as they are initialized once so i can use them as a counter . If there is another way to make a counter , then kindly put an example so that i could have a better understanding . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't return the function you return the result of the call.
Here a basic example of recursion :

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

If we call the function with n == 2 the program will do:

1) factorial (2) => return 2 * factorial(1); // It calls factorial with n == 1, do the multiplication and then return the result.

2) factorial(1) => return 1 * factorial(0); // same here with n == 0

3) factorial(0) => return 1; // from here the program will come back from the calls with the results

4) factorial(1) => return 1 * 1; => return 1;

5) factorial(2) => return 2 * 1; => return 2;

Few other things : be aware that your code will only work once as you use static int len, and count is a useless variable.

Comment: it's true that count is a useless variable but static int len is fine. Making the variable static retains its value as the function calls itself and then decrements that value; see http://codepad.org/y3yTzyNY

Answer (score 0):

The function signature indicates a return value, so you need to embed the function call in a return statement for a value to be returned by the function, especially when neither of the if-conditionals are true.

Consider the following code (a variant of what the OP provided):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int find(char f,string str) {
    static int len = str.length() - 1;
    static int count = 1;
    int temp = 0;

    if (len < 0) {
        cout << count << "\n";
        return -99;
    }
    else
    if ( str[len] == f) {
        return len;
    }

    len--;
    count++;
    temp = find( f, str );
    cout << temp << "\n";
    return temp;
}

int main() {
   char ch = 'z';
   int res = find(ch,"I");
   if (res < 0) {
      cout << "Letter '" << ch << "' was not found";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

See [demo](http://codepad.org/Ihe2SUI1)

Note that find() has a return value of -99 when the letter is not found.  That value is captured by **temp** in find() and the function then returns the value of temp.

Now, consider main() -- its signature also indicates a return value, although it is discarded.  If you attempt to execute the code without returning some kind of an integer in main(), the execution will be flawed.

So, whether you use a function recursively or not, if the function's signature indicates a return value then you need to return a value of the expected type.  Since find() may return -99 or the position of the found letter, when it executes it will evaluate as one of those two values which will be returned by means of the return statement.